# Copying a file that is a virus caused my program to terminate

Tags: c#

I have made a tool that will copy files from a source to a destination. However during the copy, the software came across a virus that was flagged by the anti-virus software (Symantec).

The anti-virus then caused my software to close down, and quarantine the program as a "dropper".

Is there anyway I can gracefully handle this scenario, rather than shutting down my program completely?

I appreciate that the action was the result of the anti-virus, but is there anything I can do to help the situation? For example, Robocopy does not just terminate when it comes across a virus.

Here is my copy code;

```
void CopyFileExactly(CopyParameterBundle cpb, bool overwrite)
{

    string CTP = "", CFP = "";
    CFP = cpb.SourcePath;

    if (cpb.RenameFile)
        CTP = cpb.DestPath ;
    else
        CTP = cpb.DestPath;

    //Check firstly if the file to copy exists
    if (!File.Exists(CFP))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    //Check if destination file exists
    //If it does, make it not read only so we can update MAC times
    if (File.Exists(CTP))
    {
        var target = GetFile(CTP);//new FileInfo(CTP);
        if (target.IsReadOnly)
            target.IsReadOnly = false;
    }

    var origin = GetFile(CFP);//new FileInfo(CFP);
    GetFile(CTP).Directory.Create();
    //(new FileInfo(CTP)).Directory.Create();

    origin.CopyTo(CTP, (overwrite ? true : false));

    if (!File.Exists(CTP))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Destination file not found!");
    }
    var destination = GetFile(CTP);//new FileInfo(CTP);
    if (destination.IsReadOnly)
    {
        destination.IsReadOnly = false;
        destination.CreationTime = origin.CreationTime;
        destination.LastWriteTime = origin.LastWriteTime;
        destination.LastAccessTime = origin.LastAccessTime;
        destination.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
        destination.CreationTime = origin.CreationTime;
        destination.LastWriteTime = origin.LastWriteTime;
        destination.LastAccessTime = origin.LastAccessTime;
    }

    if (performMD5Check)
    {
        var md5Check = compareFileMD5(CFP, CTP);
        cpb.srcMD5Hash = md5Check.Item2;
        cpb.dstMD5Hash = md5Check.Item3;
        if (!md5Check.Item1)
            throw new MD5MismatchException("MD5 Hashes do NOT match!");
    }

}
```

The calling code;

```
        void BeginCopy(int DegreeOfParallelism, int retryCount, int retryDelay)
    {
        object _lock;
        //Setup cancellation token
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
        //Set max number of threads
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DegreeOfParallelism;
        //Exceptio logging queue
        var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
        var completeItems = new ConcurrentQueue<CopyParameterBundle>();
        var erroredItems = new ConcurrentQueue<CopyParameterBundle>();

        //Logger logger = new Logger(sLogPath);

        //logger.Write("Starting copy");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(CopyParameters,
                po,
                (i, loopState, localSum) =>
                {
                    localSum = retryCount;
                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Go off and attempt to copy the file
                            DoWork(i);
                            //Incrememt total count by 1 if successfull
                            i.copyResults.TransferTime = DateTime.Now;
                            i.copyResults.TransferComplete = true;

                            completeItems.Enqueue(i);
                            //logger.Write("Copied file from: " + i.SourcePath + "\\" + i.SourceFile + "  =>  " + i.DestPath + "\\" + i.SourceFile);

                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //this.richTextBox1.AppendText("[-] Exception on: " + i.SourcePath + "\\" + i.SourceFile + "   => " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            //Exception was thrown when attempting to copy file
                            if (localSum == 0)
                            {
                                //Given up attempting to copy. Log exception in exception queue
                                exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                                this.SetErrorText(exceptions.Count());

                                //Write the error to the screen
                                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText("[-] Exception on: " + i.SourcePath + "\\" + i.SourceFile + "   => " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
                                    i.copyResults.TransferComplete = false;
                                    i.copyResults.TransferTime = DateTime.Now;
                                    i.copyResults.exceptionMsg = ex;
                                    erroredItems.Enqueue(i);

                                    //logger.Write("ERROR COPYING FILE FROM : " + i.SourcePath + "\\" + i.SourceFile + " => " + i.DestPath + "\\" + i.SourceFile + "  => " + ex.Message.ToString() + "  => " + ex.Source);
                                });
                            }
                            //Sleep for specified time before trying again
                            Thread.Sleep(retryDelay);
                            localSum--;
                        }

                        //Attempt to Repeat X times
                    } while (localSum >= 0);

                    //Check cancellation token
                    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref TotalProcessed);
                    this.SetProcessedText(TotalProcessed);

                    //Update Progress Bar
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        this.progressBar1.Value = (TotalProcessed);
                    });
                });


            //aTimer.Stop();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.label9.Text = "Process: Writing Log";
            });

            WriteLog(sLogPath, completeItems, erroredItems);

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.label9.Text = "Process: Done!";
            });

            if (exceptions.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Done with errors!");

            EnableDisableButton(this.button2, true);
            EnableDisableButton(this.button4, false);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Aren't you not worried why the file is flagged as virus? Have you checked if there is an exception thrown? Also depends on which virusscanner.

Comment: I'm not bothered if the file is a virus, it can be skipped. I ran it outside of a debugger so no, didn't collect any exception logs.

Comment: if its flagging your application as the problem, then you have much less options, because the job of the av is to terminate the app and prevent it doing further work - if it was just highlighting a file that you were copying then, it would be a cause of a few more try loops (such as around origin.CopyTo etc.)

Comment: I've updated my question with more code. I already have a retry system in place.

Comment: How do you copy the file?

Comment: I use the `CopyTo` method

Comment: How does it implemented? It does not clear from your code if it is a kind of standard method or your custom implementation.

Comment: It is the method that is part of the standard `FileInfo` class. It is not a custom implementation.

Comment: My guess is that robocopy is recognised as an official tool, thus not terminated. Your program is an unknown application, thus assumed to be potentially malicious, hence terminated when dropping virusses. The simplest solution: don't copy virusses. Besides that, you can't 'handle' being terminated by the virus scanner.

Comment: How am I to know if a file is a virus before copying? If it hasn't been picked up by the anti-virus before the copying stage, there is no way for me to know what is / isn't a virus?

Comment: Why do you care? E.g. when installing software you will often face "please disable antivirus" warning, because you can't take responsibility of false-positives (it's not your problem). If your software is terminated/blocked by antivirus, firewall or stupid user - it's their issue, not yours. All you have to do is a simple `try/catch` to handle known errors.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you did not codesign your program with a certificate from a trusted root authority.  That's a lot of money for a 2048 bit number but certainly expected when you deploy your program onto other people's machines.

Comment: CopyTo internally uses Win32Native.CopyFile that might be treated by AV specifically. Try to just open a file without being reading it. AV should just block it and you get and exception or error code (depending on method you use). In this case just skip coping the file. It might prevent from your program to be quarantined. It is just a guess but you can try it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, how you can you open a file without reading it?

Comment: e.g. using(new FileInfo(filepath).OpenRead());

Comment: Still not solved this issue. If there are any fresh insights please feel free to share them.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is most likely that the antivirus was aware of the virus file, so when it detected that a change in the file system (moving the file) occurred, it terminated the program because by moving the virus to a different location in your computer, it could cause problems (since it's a virus). It was flagged as dropper, basically a type of program that is designed to install the virus.

Edit: i forgot to mention that to solve the problem you will most likely need to license your program.